# Сохранение значения radio кнопки при перезагрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Нужно сохранить значение 'checked' у одной из радио-кнопок. Я попробовал работать с *localstorage*, но никак не получается это реализовать через JavaScript:

```js
const save = document.getElementsByName('hero');
for (var i = 0; i < save.length; i++) {
  save[i].onclick = function() {
    localStorage.setItem('Radio', this.value);
  }
}
if (localStorage.getItem('Radio')) {
  let Radio = localStorage.getItem('Radio');
  document.querySelector('input[name="hero"][value="' + Radio + '"]').setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="bA" name="hero" class="choose"><img src="#" alt="" id="A">
<input type="radio" id="bE" name="hero" class="choose"><img src="#" alt="" id="E">
```

Comment: "я попробовал работать с localstorage" - где?

Comment: const save = document.getElementsByName('hero');

for (var i = 0; i < save.length; i++) {
  save[i].onclick = function() {
    localStorage.setItem('Radio', this.value);
  }
}

if(localStorage.getItem('Radio')) {
  let Radio = localStorage.getItem('Radio');
  document.querySelector('input[name="hero"][value="' + Radio + '"]').setAttribute('checked','checked');
}

Comment: Код должен быть в [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1102600/edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Ваших радиокнопок нет `value`.

Это будет работать, когда Вы пропишете атрибут `value`:

```
let Radio = localStorage.getItem('Radio');
if (Radio) {
  let inp = document.querySelector('input[name="hero"][value="' + Radio + '"]');
  if (inp) {
    inp.checked = true;
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое)

Comment: @Wag1 Пожалуйста. Успехов!